# There is a mysterious factor when compute coeffiencts

Tags: infinite-impulse-response

everyone
i m trying write higher order butterworth algorithm in c++.I can compute nominator and denominator second order. So i tell myself , i can cascade struct for higher order. But there is between factor two cascade and fourth order.

For example;

`second order nominator a = [0,0976307608403291 0,195261521680658   0,0976307608403291]` ,

```
denominator b = [1 -0,942806027702107   0,333329071063423]
```

when i do conv(a,a) in matlab result is

```
new_a  = [0,00953176546226155   0,0381270618490462  0,0571905927735693  0,0381270618490462  0,00953176546226155]
```

but i get this coeffs when i do butter func in matlab

`butter_a = [0,0102094807912031    0,0408379231648125  0,0612568847472187  0,0408379231648125  0,0102094807912031]`

maybe you see that between constant factor butter_a and new_a and it is 1.071 like that. I wonder what is that and how can i compute this variable for more than one cascading struct ?

sorry for my bad language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're comparing the coefficients for two different filters:

1. A fourth-order Butterworth filter designed for cutoff frequency $f_c$
2. A cascade of two second-order Butterworth filters, each designed for cutoff frequency $f_c$.

The two are not equivalent to one another, although in the passband and stopband you will see similar magnitude responses. Specifically, at the cutoff frequency $f_c$, you'll see 6 dB of attenuation from filter #1, while filter #2 would give you 12 dB. Therefore, it's not unexpected that you would get slightly different coefficients for the two implementations.

Comment: ooo it's problem. So what should i do ?

Comment: It's not a problem, it just is a detail of the filter structures you're using. You didn't really give any information on what you want to accomplish, so it's hard to make a recommendation.

Comment: ofc you are right , thank you for helping to me , as i say i am writing butterworth algortihm in c++,  there isnt any constant it will generate coeffiencts nominator and denominator. So i ll type order and cutoff freq , generate coeffiencts something like that. İs there any documents for that or anything you say about that ?

Comment: Butterworth filters are probably the easiest analog filter prototype to map to a digital implementation. [The transfer function polynomials are well-known in closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter#Normalized_Butterworth_polynomials). You can very straightforwardly apply a mapping like the bilinear transform to these polynomials to get your discrete-time transfer function.